# Embed Excel in Java GUI

Tags: java, excel, qt, user-interface

I'm looking for a way to embed an Excel spread sheet into a Java GUI application. Actually into a Qt GUI build by using QtJambi. The spread sheet does not necessarily be modifiable, but a seamless presentation would be preferable to an explicit opening of the excel application.

I came up with several ideas by scanning the web:

- embed the sheet in an html file and display it by using a browser integrated in java
- j-integra (seems old, requires licencing)
- jacob (no gui support if I am correct)
- use swt.ole classes (the most promising, there's even an example on the web, problem is how to display swt in qt)
- use Qt's ActiveQt (not existent in the Java port)

Has anybody experiences concerning this topic? Any ideas that might be helpful - I would be grateful.

Regards